# How can I texture individual tiles?

Tags: modeling, texturing, tilesize

[image]

As the pic above , in the tile there us small squares , each square have its own drawnings , how can make the same tile in blender ?

Comment: Is each tile its own object, or are they all part of the same object?

Comment: they all are part of the same object .. what i need is , how to make the art inside that tile , like the circle with that flowers inside

Comment: Image texture? Seriously, what are you asking for? How to assign different materials to different parts of object or how to create flourish pattern?

Comment: the patterns you can do in any design program (inkscape, illustrator, etc) export as bitmaps and use those as texture on a plane.

Comment: and how to add the bitmaps into blender ?

Comment: im using blender cycles render

Answer (score 1):

if you have some image editor like Gimp or Photoshop you can create the composition with the diferent textures.

[image]

1.- Unwarp the rectangle
2.- export the Uv Layout

> Than create your composition in Gimp or Photoshop, with the exported UV-Layout
>   3.- In Cycles, create a Material
>   4.- and add the Image Texture Nodes with your composition image.

Comment: yes yes .. i want to like this ... thank youuu sooo much

Comment: @Rayedalharbi upvoting and / or accepting the answer is considered a "thankyou" too.